# Cómo ajusto mi codigo para que cuando no se pueda conectar a la db dada, retorne un error, pero aun así se pueda cargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

OK, tengo este codigo que hace lo siguiente:
Primero yo tengo la base de datos de muchos usuarios ya que estos para cargar una pagina con ciertas características, mi pagina se conecta a sus dbs y pregunta por ciertas características. Segundo, para hacer esto, tuve que hacer el siguiente codigo y todo ok, pero el problema es que si por ejemplo el usuario al registrarse, ingresa una contraseña incorrecta o algo incorrecto, no podré conectarme a su db, cómo puedo al momento en el que el usuario lo intenta, mandarle un error, o retornar error en este codigo y que mi pagina no se caiga cada vez que pase esto?

```
async connectExternalDb(host, user, password, db, port, type) {
        const database = {
            host: host,
            user: user,
            password: password,
            database: db,
            port: port
        }
        mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
        const pool = mysql.createPool(database);
        pool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return "error";
            }

            if (connection) connection.release();
        });

        pool.query = promisify(pool.query);
        switch (type) {

            /* --------------= BANS =-------------- */

            case 'get-bans':
                const bans = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_bans');
                pool.end();
                return bans;
            case 'get-bans-length':
                const lengthBans = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_bans');
                pool.end();
                return await lengthBans.length;
            case 'get-open-bans':
                const openBans = await pool.query(`SELECT *
                                                   FROM sc_bans
                                                   WHERE Status LIKE 'open'`);
                pool.end();
                return await openBans.length;
            case 'get-closed-bans':
                const closedBans = await pool.query(`SELECT *
                                                     FROM sc_bans
                                                     WHERE Status LIKE 'closed'`);
                pool.end();
                return await closedBans.length;

            /* --------------= REPORTS =-------------- */

            case 'get-reports':
                const reports = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_reports');
                pool.end();
                return reports;
            case 'get-reports-length':
                const lengthReports = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_reports');
                pool.end();
                return await lengthReports.length;
            case 'get-open-reports':
                const openReports = await pool.query(`SELECT *
                                                      FROM sc_reports
                                                      WHERE Status LIKE 'open'`);
                pool.end();
                return await openReports.length;
            case 'get-closed-reports':
                const closedReports = await pool.query(`SELECT *
                                                        FROM sc_reports
                                                        WHERE Status LIKE 'closed'`);
                pool.end();
                return await closedReports.length;

            /* --------------= WARNS =-------------- */

            case 'get-warns':
                const warns = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_warns');
                pool.end();
                return warns;
            case 'get-warns-length':
                const lengthWarns = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_warns');
                pool.end();
                return await lengthWarns.length;
            case 'get-open-warns':
                const openWarns = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM sc_warns WHERE Status LIKE 'open'`);
                pool.end();
                return await openWarns.length;
            case 'get-closed-warns':
                const closedWarns = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM sc_warns WHERE Status LIKE 'closed'`);
                pool.end();
                return await closedWarns.length;

            /* --------------= SERVER =-------------- */

            case 'get-server-info':
                const servers = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_servers');
                pool.end();
                return servers;
            case 'get-server-staff':
                const staff = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_servers_staff');
                pool.end();
                return staff;
            case 'get-players':
                const players = await pool.query('SELECT Name FROM sc_alts ');
                pool.end();
                return players;
            case 'get-players-length':
                const playersLength = await pool.query('SELECT Name FROM sc_alts ');
                pool.end();
                return await playersLength.length;
            default:
                const def = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sc_bans');
                pool.end();
                return def;
        }

    }
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *que mi pagina no se caiga cada vez que pase esto*? Pienso que sería de utilidad que muestres cómo haces uso de tu código en tu página. Como lo haces ahora, ¿obtienes algún error? De ser así también especifícalo.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas [ExpresJS](https://expressjs.com/) en tu backend al ocurrir un error al conectar a tu base de datos debes de enviarle un [HTTP STATUS CODE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) 500, en tu frontend al recibir un error 500 ya lo interpretas como un error en servidor y asi le haces saber al usuario que hay un error en el servidor

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
async connectExternalDb(host, user, password, db, port, type) {
        const database = {
            host: host,
            user: user,
            password: password,
            database: db,
            port: port
        }
        mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
        const pool = mysql.createPool(database);
        pool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
            if (error) {
               app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
               res.status(err.status || 500).json({status: err.status, 
               message: err.message})
               });
            }

            if (connection) connection.release();
        });

        pool.query = promisify(pool.query);
        switch (type) {
        }

    }
```